# Access Response Payload of form submit() / formObject.submit()

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit

I would like to access response payload of a `formObject.submit()`
I will use the response text as alert.

i've tried using axios but *BLOB respons*e type could not be accessed. tried it via `console.log(response.data)`

```
        const form = document.createElement('form');
        form.method = 'post';
        form.action = '/report_amortizationschedule';
        const params = {
            'loan_no': this.loanDetailno,
            'auth': _AUTH_KEY
        }

        for (const key in params) {
            if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
                hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
                hiddenField.name = key;
                hiddenField.value = params[key];

                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
            }
        }

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
```

Comment: `form.submit();` triggers a “standard” form submission, meaning the browser will consider the result as a new document to replace the old one with. If you want to have access to the returned data in JavaScript, you need to make the request _in_ JavaScript to begin with (AJAX/fetch).

Comment: Thanks, I used Ajax as you said to get the response